# How to bring product description on the custom page?

Tags: javascript, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

i have built a custom page & that is my home page &  in my store i have disabled the product page, when a user clicks on add to cart it will directly go to checkout page & now i want to show up the Product_tabs on the home page***(Tabs like Product Description,We Also Recommend,Additional Information,Product Tags)***
how can i do this some help me in solving this....

if i put this piece of code in the cms page-->layouy design then it is bringing the tabs on the home page but the java script is not working how can i resolve this issue

```
<reference name="content">
 <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
                    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>upsell_products</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same code that is used in product view template

Comment: yes as this is for tabs? if you like to implement it differently then go ahead